# ShellExecute returns 0x00000002

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to test using ShellExecute to open chrome on the initialisation of an MFC application. This is the code I am implementing:

```
HINSTANCE a = ShellExecute(NULL,"open","C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

But the functions returns the value `2` to `a`. I checked online and found that this corresponds to the file not being found, but I rechecked the path and it is correct. I also read that this could be because of the executable being administrator accessible only, but I checked this as well and it isn't. I tried using `CreateProcess` but it too was not working.

Have I understood the function wrong, or am I using it wrong? Am I missing a header? Also is it possible to open chrome and open a bookmark?

EDIT 1: I changed the backslash usage in the string literal to the following

```
ShellExecute(NULL,"open","C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Am I supposed to do the same for the colon as well? Because the function is still returning `2`.